# How do I install the latest version of node on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, upgrade, inode

I'm trying to install the latest version of node on my CentOS 7 server.  I was following the instructions here -- https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/ .  Specifically, I tried this

```
[rails@server ~]$  sudo npm cache clean -f 
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
[rails@server ~]$  sudo npm install -g n 
/usr/bin/n -> /usr/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
/usr/lib
└── n@5.0.1 

[rails@server ~]$  sudo n stable 

  installing : node-v10.16.0
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/10.16.0
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.0/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
   installed : v10.16.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v6.16.0 at /bin/node

[rails@server ~]$ node -v
v6.16.0
```

As you can see above, despite the fact it seems everythinng installed successfully, I'm still showing the older version.  Does anyone know how I can install the latest version?

Comment: It looks like you have version 6.16.0 at `/bin/node` and version 10.16.0 at `/usr/local/bin/node`.  You can verify that by running `/usr/local/bin/node -v`

Comment: When I run your command, indeed I get "v10.16.0".  What to do?  Is there a way to delete the old version?

Comment: You have not provided any information on how that older version of `node` was installed, so I cannot provide recommendations on how to completely remove it.  If you cannot find out how to uninstall it, you could probably safely rename `/usr/bin/node`.  You could configure your user's `$PATH` environment to have `/usr/local/bin` before `/bin` which should also achieve the behavior you seem to be looking for.